# Returning values of a few drop down forms made in a loop undefined index error

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a HTML form inside a PHP loop but I am having trouble returning the values of the dropdown lists after clicking my submit button. The problem is that it is returning a value for $dropdown0, but not for any other $dropdown. In this example there are 3 questions, so it should be returning $dropdown0, $dropdown1 and $dropdown2, yet when I press submit, it gives an error saying:

> Notice: Undefined index: dropdown1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\playQuiz.php on line 54
>
> Notice: Undefined index: dropdown2 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\playQuiz.php on line 55

```
for($x=0; $x<=$noQuestions-1; $x++){
    $type = "dropdown".$x;
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>"."Question ".($x+1).": ".$question[$x]."</tr>";
    echo "<form method=\"post\">";
    echo "<Select class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=$type required>";
    echo "<option value=\"1\">".$optionData[$x][0]."</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"2\">".$optionData[$x][1]."</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"3\">".$optionData[$x][2]."</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"4\">".$optionData[$x][3]."</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

The code for printing the values of the drop down lists using a button called 'submit':

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    extract($_REQUEST);

    echo $_POST['dropdown0'];
    echo $_POST['dropdown1'];
    echo $_POST['dropdown2'];
}
```

Comment: Where is your submit button?

Comment: Why `name=$type` and not `name=".$type."`

Comment: '<form>' inside `<table>` is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because you have built 3 forms inside that loop, so when you click the submit button it sends the first form only, you need to get the form element outside the loop

```
echo "<form method=\"post\">"; // << here
For($x=0; $x<=$noQuestions-1; $x++){
                $type = "dropdown".$x;
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>"."Question ".($x+1).": ".$question[$x]."</tr>";
                echo "<Select class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=$type required>";
                echo "<option value=\"1\">".$optionData[$x][0]."</option>";
                echo "<option value=\"2\">".$optionData[$x][1]."</option>";
                echo "<option value=\"3\">".$optionData[$x][2]."</option>";
                echo "<option value=\"4\">".$optionData[$x][3]."</option>";
                echo "</select>";

                echo "</table>";
            }
echo "</form>";  // << here
```